# How to gather windows from secondary monitor in Windows7?

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, extended-desktop

I sometimes use a secondary monitor (extended display) and "forget" some windows on it. When I stop using it some windows are stuck on the secondary monitor.

I would like an option to "gather" all the windows on a monitor or, at least, to move a window to another monitor (perhaps by picking it from a list or by right clicking it's taskbar button etc).

Right now I am switching between projection modes (<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>). Is there a simpler solution?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can use keyboard shortcuts for window management. Use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> to select the window that you want to move and then press <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Left/Right</kbd> to move from one monitor to another.

You may also want to try out <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Left/Right/Up/Down</kbd>

Comment: Tried it now, doesn't seem to work.

Comment: which one didn't work? are you using windows 7?

Comment: Doesn't work for me either. Win7 here. Maybe because the app in question is either minimized or fullscreen, but never a window.

Comment: This doesn't gather all the windows to the current monitor

Comment: This also works in Windows 10.

Answer (score 9):

Got a solution.

I had the same problem using a C compiler, everytime I run an application, its text window was opened in the wrong place (the extended monitor).

Switch to the 'lost' window. Use any means to make it appear (one of the recipes commented in this page).

Right click on the upper left corner of the window to open the menu,
OR
press ALT+SPACE.

Chose 'properties'.
Search in the menu for 'let the system position the window'. Check the option.

Voilà.

Comment: Had the same problem with Slack. It has driven me nuts for months on end, not being able to get it back with ALT+TAB or WINDOWS+LEFT. Thanks so much more the ALT+SPACE trick! (I use maximize as there was no properties option)

Comment: This maximize solution should be included somewhere! I already used Alt+Space to make the menu show up, but neither Move would, nor would I have a properties option. Maximize did the trick!

Comment: Neither Windows 7 or 10 has the _Properties_ item in the window context menu (`ALT` + `SPACE`). Are you using any application which adds it there?

Comment: Worked for "FileAlyzer", all other options didn't

Answer (score 6):

Sometimes when we disconnect the secondary monitor, We do not get all the windows tabs to our primary screen.

To get all those back to primary screen once you are no longer connected to secondary monitor, I have a workaround.
1-With <kbd>WIN</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>, try with `computer only` in projector option

If not solved Then

2-With <kbd>WIN</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>, select `duplicate` for projector option
And again With <kbd>WIN</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>, select `computer only` or `Disconnect Projector` option.

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: Great answer, thanks. I'm not sure why this didn't get more votes. It's the only thing that worked for me, for a game running in windowed mode.

Comment: I needed to move all windows not just one. On windows 10 this is pretty slick. You just have to hit second monitory only, then all the windows move, then click back to extended and all the windows stay. Very nice work around.

Answer (score 4):

If you right click on the programs taskbar button you will get the option to 'move' the window (maybe you need to <kbd>Shift</kbd> + right click, I'm using a Linux computer at the moment).

Press the right (or left depending on were your windows are...) cursor button to move the window to your desktop.

Alternative: <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> to the program, then <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd>, press <kbd>M</kbd>, use cursors to bring the window to you.

Answer (score 4):

None of the above worked for me. What did work was:

Right-Click icon in taskbar (icon of application whose window is invisible).

Select Maximize (or Alt SPACE x via the keyboard).

Comment: This was the ticket for me when I lost a window switching from a huge resolution in RDP to a tiny one in VNC

Comment: I was able to right-click on the *preview* of the invisible application in the taskbar (which comes after hovering over the icon for a second or two) and then select maximize. Right-clicking on the icon itself only offered the close action.