# How to gather *prompt* window from secondary screen no longer attached (using Windows 7)

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, utorrent

I use a Windows 7dell laptop sometimes connected to a docking station with dual monitors attached (to the dock). It's not uncommon for me to sleep the computer, undock, and resume elsewhere.

Occasionally, an app (best example is uTorrent) will leave a prompt window on the "ghost" monitor no longer attached. I have tried the alt+space method [suggested here](https://superuser.com/questions/216277/windows7-how-to-gather-windows-from-secondary-monitor), and also tried using <kbd>win</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> function... the rub comes from the fact that this prompt window doesn't show up in the <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> stack, nor in the <kbd>win</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> stack. (In uTorrent, the window I'm talking about is the window that appears after downloading via "Open with" or clicking a .torrent link, prompting for the location of the file to be saved and other options for use while downloading.) I've also tried the <kbd>win</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> method of

On a mac I would just use "Gather windows" in the system preferences under displays, but there seems to be no option for this (that I can find) in Win7.

How can I gain focus on the prompt window, or more helpful: How can I force all windows to a certain display on Windows 7?

Also, I tried to add the "gather-windows" Tag, since it seems there are several users trying to address similar questions, but alas, not enough reputation...

Comment: It might be simple, but have you tried right clicking on the task bar and selecting `Cascade windows` or `Show windows stacked`?

Comment: Yes, however, this doesn't succeed either; my guess is that since the window isn't in the "zstack" it doesn't respond when the cascade command is given. However, I'll make sure to try it again the next time the problem appears and report back.

Answer (score 1):

Use <kbd>win</kbd> +<kbd>left arrow</kbd> or <kbd>right arrow</kbd>.